# assigning a value to a class object

Tags: python, class

i'm tasked with the job to create a class of strings and integers between 1 and 10.

I basically did the following...

```
class hello():
     __slots__ = ('name', 'number')
    def __init__(self):
          self.name = myName
          self.number = myNumber
```

The only problem is that I don't know how to make myNumber = an integer between 1 and 10. Similarly, how would I compare myNumber if it's assigned to a name to other objects? Thanks

Comment: As for the conversion, you should be able to use the `int()` function, that is built into python. I am not sure what you mean by "how would I compare myNumber if it's assigned to a name to other objects?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You the constructor and enforce a check at assignment. Try doing this with the `property` decorator:

```
class MyClass():

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.something = value

    @property
    def something(self):
        return self.item

    @something.setter
    def set_something(self, value):
        if value is not None:
            self.time = value
        else:
            raise Error
```

This is one way to put in logic which prevents setting a `None` value on a property of a class. You could also doing something with this to change it to check the values you want it to be.